# Crystal Reports XI - passing shared varibables

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a subreport that calculates a value per patient. I want to pass that to the main report. It is passing 0.00
In subreport detail line I have the formula:
 Whileprintingrecords;
 Shared  Numbervar  restraintot:= {Command.RESTRAINT_TIME_DAYS}

In the main report on the page header line I have the formula
Shared Numbervar restraintot;
Restraintot;

It is pulling the first value and putting that on every line. 
Do I need to also add a parameter or something to connect it to each patient?
Please help

Comment: Page header will pick first value..... Can you give brief of the report

Comment: Post Your report structure here